# Create Multiple Excel sheet in VC++

Tags: c++, excel, visual-c++, office-interop

How to create Excel file with multiple worksheet in VC++ and save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is `XL->Worksheets->Add();` Worksheets are added in reverse order.

```
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\mso.dll"
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VBA\VBA6\VBE6EXT.OLB"
#import "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\excel.exe" \
rename("DialogBox","ExcelDialogBox") rename("RGB","ExcelRGB") \
exclude("IFont","IPicture")

#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  CoInitialize(NULL);
  try
  {
    Excel::_ApplicationPtr XL;
    HRESULT hr = XL.CreateInstance(L"Excel.Application");

    Excel::_WorkbookPtr workbook = XL->Workbooks->Add(Excel::xlWorksheet); 
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr worksheet = XL->ActiveSheet;
    worksheet->Name = "last page";

    worksheet = XL->Worksheets->Add(); // adding worksheets!!
    worksheet->Name = "other page";

    worksheet = XL->Worksheets->Add();
    worksheet->Name = "some page";

    worksheet->SaveAs("c:\\test.xls");
    workbook->Close();
    XL->Quit();
  }
  catch(_com_error &ce)
  {
    std::cout<<"caught" << std::endl;
  }

  CoUninitialize();

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel supports XML from 2003 onwards. XML can have multiple worksheets.

You can generate an XML file from VC++. This XML cab be opened as an Excel worksheet by Excel.

To look for format/structure of XML, create an excel file and enter data for few cells in couple of sheets. Then save the file as XML.

You can write code to generate similar XML.

Comment: XL->Workbooks->Add(Excel::xlWorksheet);Excel::_WorksheetPtr pSheet = XL->ActiveSheet; pSheet->SaveAs(szExcelFileName.GetBuffer()); I am using this code save the xl sheet but, it is saving only Activesheet only. I need to save all sheets within xls file.

Comment: Instead of :

pSheet->SaveAs(szExcelFileName.GetBuffer());

Do :

XL->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs(szExcelFileName.GetBuffer());

Comment: XL->ActiveWorkbook->SaveAs(szExcelFileName.GetBuffer()); This is not valid method.

Comment: ActiveWorkbook should be part of XL->Workbooks

Answer (score 0):

See [Excel Object Model Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) and/or [How to find and use Office object model documentation](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222101) to find the correct methods to call. The SaveAs and SaveCopyAs methods in the Workbook interface are probably what you are looking for.